# Finding TCP connections with pids

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, terminal, pid

I tried to display all the TCP connections with pids on ubuntu terminal but am not able to do it. Can someone tell a single command to find all tcp connections with pids on ubuntu terminal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at lsof man page. I found:

[sudo] lsof -i TCP